# unknown_publisher: Ignoring transform for child_frame_id "link1"

Tags: ros, gazebo, rviz, ros-kinetic, joint-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. Currently I want to simulate random robot, which not provide ROS related files at all, to ROS environment.

Most of manufacturer provide 3D cad file(.step).

And I do some search to make urdf file from cad file, finally I figure it out THERE IS a add-in function in solidworks(wiki.ros.org/sw_urdf_exporter).

However, unfortunately, it shows error message as below.

```
[ERROR] [1542609991.430536188]: Ignoring transform for child_frame_id "link1" from authority "unknown_publisher" because of a nan value in the transform (-nan -nan -nan) (-nan -nan -nan -nan)

[ERROR] [1542609991.430645045]: Ignoring transform for child_frame_id "link1" from authority "unknown_publisher" because of an invalid quaternion in the transform (-nan -nan -nan -nan)

[ERROR] [1542609991.430670924]: Ignoring transform for child_frame_id "link2" from authority "unknown_publisher" because of a nan value in the transform (-nan -nan -nan) (-nan -nan -nan -nan)

[ERROR] [1542609991.430689004]: Ignoring transform for child_frame_id "link2" from authority "unknown_publisher" because of an invalid quaternion in the transform (-nan -nan -nan -nan)
```

https://github.com/Jungduri/HX300L.git
Here is the code that I made.

OS: ubuntu 16.04 LTS(VMware)
ROS: kinetic

Any comments will helpful.
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/308868/unknown_publisher:-ignoring-transform-for-child_frame_id-%22link1%22/) by [jungduri](https://answers.ros.org/users/38608/jungduri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-11-19

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nabihandres](https://answers.ros.org/users/47381/nabihandres/) on 2019-10-25**:
that is correct, you need to check the correct axis in the joint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First issue: some of the `joint`s don't have their `axis` property set correctly ([this one](https://github.com/Jungduri/HX300L/blob/cf8473a9308d5ef99410fa9af2e9b12e27636f30/urdf/HX300L.urdf#L93-L94) for instance). That would be something to check and fix.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jungduri](https://answers.ros.org/users/38608/jungduri/) on 2018-11-19**:
@gvdhoorn, It works. It makes matrix all zero? So it didn't work?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-11-19**:
Sometimes the SolidWorks2URDF plugin has difficulty detecting the correct mates/axis. It's not a perfect plugin (but what software is).

**Comment by [rsankhye97](https://answers.ros.org/users/133965/rsankhye97/) on 2023-01-12**:
I'm getting a similar error and it would be worth mentioning what you mean by axis property being correctly set? How should it be set? For instance here is my code. What's going wrong here https://github.com/rsankhye97/gantry_urdf/tree/main/src/end_effector_slide_gantry